# Change initial ViewController if user has entered a passcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13, swift5

I have this login screen as the initial view controller: [image: login screen image]

Once they enter a passcode it takes them to the next view controller. But how can I set this up so it only shows up once (the first time), and not every time they open the app?

Thank you!!

Comment: You mean that if the user fully close the app from the app switcher, and open it again (not from background), you want to display the second viewcontroller, right?

Comment: @balazs630 Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When user taps `Submit` button, then just save that fact as a value in `UserDefaults`:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword")
```

And then, you can check the condition inside of your `AppDelegate` file if the user has given password before and redirect the user to another screen like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  let hasSession: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword") ?? false
  let vc: UIViewController = {
            if hasSession {
                // next vc you want to show
            } else {
                // enter password vc
            }
  }()

  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  window?.rootViewController = navigationController
  window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  return true
}
```

Also, don't forget to delete that value when you want the user to enter the password again:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword")
```

Comment: For a quick solution it will work, but it's not a good idea to store such sensitive information in UserDefaults. It can be easily modified, so someone could bypass the  passcode screen.

Comment: The author didn't ask for a complex way of saving and storing any kind of sensitive data. The author asked for a solution and this answer solves his/her problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! But I get these errors: https://imgur.com/a/lVs53Gx

Comment: @EliaBaitel Please add `var window: UIWindow?` above the function, inside of `AppDelegate` file. Also, make this modification: `let hasSession: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword") ?? false`. It should work now.

Comment: I've modified the answer. Let me know if all is good. And, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct if the fix works.

Comment: Thank you again! But I'm still getting an error: https://imgur.com/a/9EKtjDY

Comment: change it to `let hasSession = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword") as? Bool
        let vc: UIViewController = {
          if let hasSession = hasSession, hasSession == true {
              // next vc you want to show
          } else {
              // enter password vc
          }
        }()`

Comment: I'm now getting this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495781/error-missing-return-in-a-closure-expected-to-return-uiviewcontroller-xcode Does anyone have an idea why? Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

you can set a BOOL in NSUserDefaults and check it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of Appdeledate.m

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:"PasswordSubmitted"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

To check it you can use: BOOL passwordSubmitted = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:"PasswordSubmitted"];

```
if(passwordSubmitted){
     //move to next screen
}
else{
    //Show password screen
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged for swift, not objc