# Error: Missing return in a closure expected to return 'UIViewController' (Xcode, Swift, iOS 13)

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, swift5

I'm getting the error: "Missing return in a closure expected to return 'UIViewController'" on the bolded line. How can I fix this? Thank you!!

```
   Var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()


let hasSession = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword") as? Bool
     let vc: UIViewController = {
               if let hasSession = hasSession, hasSession == true {
                    // next vc you want to show
                } else {
                    // enter password vc
                }
      **}()**

      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
      window?.rootViewController = navigationController
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      return true


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to return **ViewController** inside closure

```
Var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

let Myvc = UIViewController()

let hasSession = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "UserHasSubmittedPassword") as? Bool
     let vc: UIViewController = {
               if let hasSession = hasSession, hasSession == true {
                    // next vc you want to show
                       return Myvc
                } else {
                    // enter password vc
                        return Myvc
                }
      **}()**

      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
      window?.rootViewController = navigationController
      window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
      return true
    }
```